# How can the camera follow two things ? cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I’ll try to make it as simple as i can :
I’m building a game wit a main character lets call him ” Dude ”

I wrote a code that makes the camera follow Dude

```
[self runAction: [ CCFollow actionWithTarget:Dude ];
```

and i have button that makes dude go 20 pixels to the right , but after he goes those 20 pixels i cant see the button .

how can i make the button follow dude ? ( and meybe more things also follow Dude )

thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

If you want have a buttons in the same place all the time and use CCFollow you should have 3 layers.

GameLayer where you add Dude and run CCFollow

ControlLayer where you add every controls like button

ThirdLayer where you add GameLayer and ControlLayer, this is a layer which you add to scene

In this way when your GameLayer change position following by dude, the ControlLayer is in the same place

Comment: I dont really know how to work with layer im really new at cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

Put the Dude on a separate `CCNode` or `CCLayer`, and move that. Something like:

```
CCNode *dudeNode = [CCNode node];
dudeNode.position = ccp(0,0);
[self addChild:dudeNode];
[dudeNode addChild:Dude];

[dudeNode runAction: [ CCFollow actionWithTarget:Dude ];
```

Comment: I saw " node " couple times but didnt really understood what it is , but i want to try your code - where should i write it ?